# Parse datetime with desirable view

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a string with datetime "2016-03-26T07:53:48.954685Z"

Is there any custom methods/libraries to make it the "26 March, 2016"?

I can parse the string myself, of course.

Comment: Look at answer from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3552496/1015690

Comment: Parsing dates in JS is pretty challenging as you may struggle with Browser inconsistencies. As said above, check out moment.js